# How to add a notification in system tray?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase Cloud Messaging to receive notifications on my Flutter App. Further I'm using "overlay_support" plugin to display the notification.

Now on receiving a notification from FCM it's displayed properly like this :

[image]

But I wanted to know how can I add this notification in the system tray :

[image]

I want the notification to be displayed here along with the pop up.

Currently I'm using the test notification feature of FCM.

This this the code of the callback :

```
static Future<dynamic> onMessageCallback(Map<String,dynamic> message){
    print("GgWWP");
    showOverlayNotification((context) {
      return Card(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: ListTile(
            leading: SizedBox.fromSize(
                size: const Size(40, 40),
                child: ClipOval(
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ))),
            title: Text('Notifiaction'),
            subtitle: Text('You have received a new Notification'),
            trailing: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                onPressed: () {
                  OverlaySupportEntry.of(context).dismiss();
                }),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 4000));
  }
```

Thankyou in advance for helping.

Comment: Were you able to figure out how to do this ? If yes, please share it.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications Look into this package.